# How to find a string in a dataframe column value

Tags: python-3.x, string, pandas, contains

I have a dataframe called `tf_df` that has several columns, including one called `'Val_Combined'`. I want to create a new dataframe out of the items where ``Val_Combined`contain the string`'VALID'` (it may contain other characters as well). I have tried the following:

```
t1_valid_df = t1_df[(t1_df['Val_Combined'].contains('VALID'))]
```

This throws an error:

> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'contains'

What is the correct approach to achieve my goal?

Comment: if you need to check multiple values pd.DataFrame(if any(str(elem) in ['VALID','INVALID'] for elem in df['Val_Combined'].tolist())):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)

try this.

```
t1_valid_df = t1_df[(t1_df['Val_Combined'].str.contains('VALID'))]
```

Comment: That was it; I didn't realize I had to include the '.str'.